# Is there an accepted term for this monotonicity property?

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology

Given a vector space $V$ over the reals, I have a function $f:V \to \mathbb{R}$ with properties:

$$f(\vec 0) = 0$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x\vec v) > 0 \;\;\forall\;\vec v \in V, x \geq 0$$

Is there an accepted term for this property? "Positive definite" isn't correct. "Norm" is too restrictive. "Radially monotone" seems like a good choice, but it doesn't appear anywhere online.

I'm content to use "radially monotone", but I'd like to use a more standard terminology if one exists.